# Reset Server password With FTP credentials

Tags: passwords, windows-server-2008-r2

OS: WIndows server 2008 R2 VPS (Physically Not Accessible)
Problem : Ransom-ware attacked and changed the login credentials for all administrators & users.
Status : Ftp login enabled with parental drive access + A standard user with credentials till login screen with error "The Group Policy Client Service Failed The Logon. Access is denied".

Support Required:
1. Password reset by replacing files or changing saved password. or
2. Replace cmd.exe to some other program before svchost.exe to grab a command prompt to reset password at logon.

Please help. Every possible directions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You will be unable to reset the server password, if all you have, is FTP credentials.  I suggest you load up a backup of your VM from before the infection.

Comment: No recent backup available.

Comment: You are out of luck in that case.